# How create a cascading connection between two drop-down lists in SQL/Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a link between two drop down lists on microsoft access. Indeed, my first drop-down list has all the column names of my table, and I would like in SQL or directly on Access to have a method which when we select a column in the first drop-down list, it returns the list of records without duplicates in the second drop-down list.

My end goal is to create a form that filters my table based on the selected column name and row
I already have a first drop-down list that displays the column names but I think that in the second drop-down list, you have to put an SQL formula in its "content":

Select * FROM table WHERE column selected

[my form on access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr3YM.png)

I'd be very thankful for all the ideas!

Comment: If you want a ComboBox options to depend on another control in your form (another ComboBox, for example), the easiest way I can think to do this is to update the Row source property of your dependent combo box using VBA every time the value in the first combo box changes. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.change) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.rowsource).

Comment: Build a query that 1. Uses `DISTINCT` clause; 2. Has the criteria for the filtering column set to `Forms!YourFormName!YourFirstComboBox` . Then set your combobox2 `RowSource property` to the query name you just saved.  You can add a ComboBox2.Requery line to the `AfterUpdate` event of ComboBox1.

Comment: Hello Barranka and dbmitch, Thanks for your answer, but what I would like is to be able to display all the columns of my table in my dropdown list and not just a specific column, and the possibility that an addition of a new column in my table can be updated also in my drop-down list. The advice you gave me only applies to a specific column, but I would like to be able to have the choice for several columns stored in a drop-down list. Does the VBA code have to apply it for all the names of my columns?

Comment: I also found a trick to display all my columns in a drop-down list by putting in RowSourceType= field list and in RowSource my table

Comment: Because fields in SQL statment in second combobox cannot be dynamic, RowSource must be modified by VBA. I have done this. Takes a bunch of code. When you have some with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 0):

frm : unbound main form
frm_sf : subform populate with the table Customers (Northwind.accdb)
cboListeFields : unbound combobox - Row source (contenu) property = Customers - Row source type (origine source) = Field list (liste des champs)
Event Procedure : cboListeFields_AfterUpdate()

```
Private Sub cboListeFields_AfterUpdate()
Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "SELECT [" & Me.cboListeFields & "] FROM Customers"
    Me.cboListeValues.RowSource = strSql
End Sub
```

cboListeValues : unbound combobox - Row source type (origine source) = Table/Query (Tables/Requêtes)
Event Procedure : cboListeValues_AfterUpdate()

```
Private Sub cboListeValues_AfterUpdate()
    Me.frm_sf.Form.FilterOn = False
    If IsNumeric(Me.cboListeValues) Then
        Me.frm_sf.Form.Filter = "[" & Me.cboListeFields & "] = " & Me.cboListeValues
        Me.frm_sf.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.frm_sf.Form.Filter = "[" & Me.cboListeFields & "] = '" & Me.cboListeValues & "'"
        Me.frm_sf.Form.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX3yA.jpg)